# package org.apache.commons.net.telnet does not exist

Tags: java, classpath, telnet

I'm writing code to establish a telnet session to a router. I saw a similar thread where the solution was to download the package and set the class path to point to the jar files. I did that.

I have `commons-net-3.3` and `commons-net-3.3-source` and `commons-net-examples-3.3` in the `jdk/lib` folder. i have configured the classpath variable to point here.

Based on another thread I read, I also installed the `ant-commons-net-1.8.1` jar file.

In spite of this when I compile my code, it shows the same error:

> package org.apache.commons.net.telnet does not exist

Comment: So either your classpath is incorrect, the versions of the JAR you have are not compatible, or you don't have that class.

Comment: classpath should point to the location of the jar files correct? my class path variable points there.. as for compatibility issues, how do i know which version to download?

Comment: I use maven and it makes sure the right versions are downloaded and added to the class path.  You need to include the path of the JAR itself, not just the directory the JAR is in.

Comment: Thanks. I used the wild card character to include all the jar files in the folder..